# how to calculate the number of posts in a category and by author

Tags: jquery, wordpress

with the code below,
I manage to get the number of posts per author.
How to add a category filter "neuws" to this query.
In order to count the number of posts by author in the "neuws" category
Thanks for the help

```
<?php
//pour voir les journees de peches de mebres en ayant deja postees et le nombre de journees
// 1. We define the arguments to define what we want to recover
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '16',
    
);

// 2. We run the WP Query
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query ($args);

// 3. we display the number of messages and the authors!
// The Loop
if ($the_query-> have_posts()) {
    //Set arguments to grab all authors with published peches, and order them by user ID
    $authorArgs = array(
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'has_published_posts' => array('post',),
        
    );

    //Create an array of all authors with peches published
    $pecheAuthors = get_users($authorArgs);

    //Loop through each peche author
    foreach($pecheAuthors as $user){
        //Output user post count for peches
        echo'<font color="#f00;"><b>';
        echo count_user_posts($user->ID, 'post');
        echo'</b></font>';
        echo ' journees de pêches pour ';

        //Output user's display name
        echo'<font color="#f00;"><b>';
        echo $user->display_name;
        echo'</b></font>';
        echo '<br />';
    }

    // 3. We launch the loop to display the articles and the authors!
    // The Loop
    
} else {
    // no posts found
}
//wp_reset_postdata ();?
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_usernumposts` filter hook. try the below code. code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function count_author_post_by_category( $count, $userid, $post_type, $public_only ){

    $author_posts = new WP_Query(array(
        'author'         => $userid,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'neuws', // your category slug.
            )
        )
    ));

    if( $author_posts->have_posts() ) {
        $count = $author_posts->found_posts;
    }

    return $count;

}
add_filter( 'get_usernumposts', 'count_author_post_by_category', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the code
but I would like to be able to display it in a page of my site

Comment: Where do you want to display it?

Comment: Thanks for the help .On my homepage if possible. But the best would be to be able to integrate it into a shordcode, this way I can display it wherever I want

Comment: I gave the answer to the original question you have asked. you are asking now for another requirement that

Comment: My request has not changed. I want to display the number of publications of the neuws category by author. Like this

 13 neuws of the category "neuws" for author A
22 neuws of the category "neuws" for author B
47 neuws of the category "neuws" for author C
ect ...

Comment: with the code I gave I just want us to add a filter for the neuw category

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by creating a custom WP_Query and then counting it.
Note: You can replace the static ID of the user with your `$userid` variable.

```
$args = array( 
   'author' => 1,
   'cat'    => 5,
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$my_count = $my_query->post_count;
```

Alternatively, you can use the category slug or author's nice name (NOT name!) as well:

```
$args = array(
   'author_name'   => 'bob',
   'category_name' => 'editorial',
};
```

Thank You,
Usman Khalid

Comment: Thanks for the code but in this case I would only have the results for a single user
I want to know the number of posts for the neuw category of each user